# Function call when object is missing from class python

Tags: python, class, oop, object, missing-data

I'm looking for a way to call a function when you try to perform a class function on an object that doesn't exist, similar to `__missing__` for dictionaries.

```
class Foo:

  def pront(self):
    print(self)

  def doesntexist(self):
    pass #do stuff

object1 = Foo
object1.pront() #works
object2.pront() #calls the doesntexist function
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Relevant: [SO:calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. How would Python know that `object2` - which doesn't exist, was *intended* to be `Foo` if it had existed?

You could make an argument that it could be literally any class at all.